# Выбор последнего класса jQuery

Tags: jquery

Как при клике на box-1 применять стили только к sub-box-1, при клике на box-2 применять стили к sub-box-2 и т.д. Количество блоков неограниченно. Вручную прописывать не вариант. Нужно универсальное решение. Есть вариант отлавливать последние классы box и sub-box и сравнивать, но не знаю как реализовать.

```html
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-1"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-1"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
```

Comment: Если есть возможность, то лучше поменять разметку, вложив sub-box внутрь необходимых box. Тогда бы при клике вы легко нашли необходимые вам элементы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".box").click(function(){
  var selector = [];
  var classes = this.classList;
  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if ($(".sub-" + classes[i]).length)
      selector.push(".sub-" + classes[i]);
  }
  console.log(selector.join(","));
  if (selector.length)
    $(selector.join(",")).addClass("pink");
});
```

```css
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  background:lightgreen;
}
.pink {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-1"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-1"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box sub-box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
```